# The Layout file exists but is not in the layout folder. Where can i find the layout file?

Tags: android

I am checking a code but i cannot find the layout file in the layout folder but it does exist. Where can i find it? I have tried to search for it in the values folder as it was mentioned in a similar stack overflow problem but there is no res file in it.

```
 try{
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.list_item, new ArrayList()));

        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null",    

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The file R.layout.list_item exists but it is not present in the layout folder

Comment: Could you post some code ? So we can see exactly what it is ?

Comment: Did you right click on the Res folder and tell it to "Refresh"?  Because just having the file in the physical folder on the drive, doesn't mean the workspace knows it's part of the project.

Comment: I cant even find the workspace folder  as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2):

**android.R.layout.list_item**,

This is is the built-in-XML layout resource file that is the part of **Android OS**.

**In Android Studio:**

Project Window -> External Libraries -> Android X Platform -> res -> layout, and here you will see a list of available layouts.

Comment: There is this file named R.layout.simple_list_item_checked as well.. Where can i find it?

Comment: Find it as I suggested above, if you are using eclipse just put the mouse over it and click on open declaration

Comment: Thanxx! It exists , so now should i place this file into the layout folder in the Android Window?

Comment: No need,  it will be taken directly as it is default value present in Android OS

Answer (score 0):

A layout file is just a layout file if it is in a layout directory. To find your xml file you can use android studios search. How do you know that this xml file exists when it's not placed in your layout directory and you moved it not.

Comment: I am checking a code for some project but i know the file exists as there is no error. When i change the name it shows that there is no file named such.

Comment: have you cleared the project? Maybe you are using a android framework xml file.

Comment: No. I have not cleared anything, the whole project is existing. I just discovered that the workspace folder also does not exist. What is the reason behind all of this?

Comment: I think AndroidHackers answer is the solution. You're using a android layout file, that is not part of your own application but of the android framework itself.